# Cannot resole keyword 'carmodel' into field. Choices are: exterior_color, id, interior_color

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, filter

As I want to filter on foreign key, I used `carmodel` with __ in the method `dropdownlistsearch()` of `views.py`. When run the code, it tells it must be a field. I don't understand this part. Why do I get this error. And I am using django 1.6.5.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class CarInfo(models.Model):0
    vin_number = models.CharField(max_length = 17)
    model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.vin_number

    class CarModel(models.Model):
        model = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.model
```

**views.py**

```
def dropdownsearch(request):
    try:
        q = request.GET.get('q')
    except:
        q = None

    if q:
        cars = CarInfo.objects.filter(carmodel__model__contains=q)
        template ='productions/resultstwo.html'
    else:
        template = 'prodcutions/cars.html'
    context = {}

    return render(request,template,context)
```

**cars.html**

```html
<form action="/cars/s/" method="get">                        
    <select name="q">
    {% for info in modelinfos %}
        <option value="{{info.model}}">{{info.model}}</option>                                 
    {% endfor %}
    </select>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are filtering on the forward relationship, so you use the actual field you have defined, `model`.

```
CarInfo.objects.filter(model__model__contains=q)
```

Comment: I tried this. And when I do this it says unboundLocalError at /cars/s/

Comment: local variable 'context' referenced before assignment

Comment: Well yes. Have you defined context in that branch of the if statement?

Answer (score -1):

def testform(request):
    form = CarInfo(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit = False)
        save_it.save()
    return render_to_response("productions/testform.html",locals(),context_instance = RequestContext(request))